# Clear Heroku logs (command)

Tags: heroku, command, logging

How could I clear `heroku logs`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`heroku restart` will clear logs - although if you're running in production you may not want to do this on a whim :D

Other than that you can use the advanced logging addon (Syslog drains), which gives you the ability to clear the logs:

**deprecated**

`heroku logs:drains clear`

**Update 2019/08/07**

`heroku drains`

More info: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: Thats deprecated
Use heroku drains as of Aug 2012

Comment: This isn't true though.

heroku restart simply adds onto the logs the restart activity.

Comment: +1 for the `heroku logs:drains clear` command. Restart keeps the log (which is the right behavior IMO)

Comment: `heroku logs:drains` has been deprecated and replaced with `heroku drains`

Answer (score 17):

The current command to clear logs is

```
heroku drains
```

Comment: Lots has changed since this answer. Get more details here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains

Answer (score 15):

Currently, there is no way to clear the Heroku logs. Heroku maintains a record of the past 1500 lines of log activity.